# Difference-in-difference with discrete treatment intensity

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

In my context I have individuals who receive treatment with an intensity of 1 to 5 once a policy has been implemented. I've seen many posts on continuous treatment and how to estimate a DD model in that case, but none for a case where treatment is discrete but not a dummy.

What would be a good specification for this case?

Comment: Can individuals/units only experience one level of intensity, or can they move up and down this intensity ladder over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setting, all you need to do is distinguish between the different treatment groups. Once your policy is in place, treated individuals fall into one of the five discrete groups representing a different dosage of treatment. Assuming the policy affects all individuals at the same time, though this also applies to settings where a policy is rolled out at different times, the model would looking something like the following:

$$
y_{it} = \gamma_i + \lambda_t + \delta_1(T^{1}_i \cdot P_t) + \delta_2(T^{2}_i \cdot P_t) + \delta_3(T^{3}_i \cdot P_t) + \delta_4(T^{4}_i \cdot P_t) + \delta_5(T^{5}_i \cdot P_t) + X_{it}'\theta + u_{it},
$$

where we observe outcome $y$ for individual $i$ in time $t$. One way to proceed is to regress this outcome on $\gamma_i$ and $\lambda_t$, which denote, respectively, *individual* and *time* fixed effects. In the next series of parenthetical expressions, we interact a treatment indicator, $T^{j}_i$, denoting the $j$-th intensity group (i.e., $J = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$), with $P_t$, a post-treatment indicator. Treated individuals should fall into one of the five groups, separated by a different intensity of policy exposure. To be clear, the *levels* of treatment shouldn't enter the model as continuous. We don't know anything about individual $i$ receiving a dose of, say, 2.5 or 3.1 units of the policy exposure. All we know is we have five levels of treatment, and each level is just more intense than the previous one. The intrinsic ordering of the exposure allows us to assess discrete dosage effects. Note that this model *assumes* we have a subset of individuals that **never receive any dose of treatment**. The model is comparing the effect of treatment generally. In other words, we're comparing the effect of the $j$-th intensity group with individuals that never received any dose at all.

Now suppose all individuals in your sample receive some level of exposure. In other words, everyone is exposed to the policy, but at different dosages. Well, we can't estimate the effect of all five levels independently; we need a viable comparison group. The low dose group (i.e., $T^1_i$) seems like a good candidate to serve as a reference. Now each discrete level of treatment is compared with the low exposure group. In this setting, you'd be estimating four distinct treatment effects, each of which show the effect of treatment at a *higher intensity*.